# Bulb example with on off button in HTML

Tags: html, css, web

I got a code which is used for bulb on and off by touching the image. But

How to modify the code with two buttons On and Off. ?  Pls help

## Edit

Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <body>
   <h1>JavaScript Can Change Images</h1>
   <img id="myImage" onclick="changeImage()" src="pic_bulboff.gif" width="100" height="180">
   <p>Click the light bulb to turn on/off the light.</p> 
  <script>
   function changeImage() { 
      var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
      if (image.src.match("bulbon")) {
         image.src = "pic_bulboff.gif"; 
      } 
     else { 
        image.src = "pic_bulbon.gif"; } 
      } 
 </script> 
 </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Show the code and what you are trying to do

Comment: Since the q is on hold, here is an example that will work for you. <!DOCTYPE html> <html> <body> 
 <h1>JavaScript Can Change Images</h1> 
 <img id="myImage"  src="on.png" width="100" height="180"> <p>Click the light bulb to turn on/off the light.</p> 
 <script> function changeImage(img) { var image = document.getElementById('myImage'); image.src = img+".gif" ;} </script> 
 <button onclick="changeImage('pic_bulbon')">ON</button><button onclick="changeImage('pic_bulboff')">OFF</button> </body> </html>

Comment: @AnshuPrateek - this will add the buttons, but will not move the on/off functionality to them unless you also update the jQuery

Comment: Jquery??? It's native JS. And I have updated the js.

Comment: @AnshuPrateek - sorry about that. You're correct re jQuery vs JS. I didn't read closely enough <insert sheepish grin>